# Why is the let variable = x syntax not working with the ternary operator?

Tags: swift, swift2

Implicitly unwrapping optionals can be done this way.

```
if let foo = foo {
     print("foo")
} else {
     print("bar")
}
```

I'm practicing in Playground, and what I don't understand is why I can't do the one above using a ternary operator.

```
let foo = foo ? print("foo") : print("bar")

// or

var result:String = (let foo = foo ? print("foo") : print("bar"))
```

I was thinking this is perfectly normal, albeit awkward, syntax for Swift since ternary operations evaluate to expressions. My suspicion is that `let foo = foo` is itself an expression that Swift has to deal with, but that's coming from a Swift newbie like me.

Comment: I believe your first example is called `Optional Binding`. Implicitly unwrapping is `someVar!`.

Comment: And the reason your second example doesn't work is because you're using `foo` in its own initial value, hence the error: `Variable used within its own initial value`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with 'let foo = foo' anyway

Comment: @Eendje I was thinking if optional binding works with ternary operators, and the result of either `true` or `false` case would be returned/assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if let` is a special Swift form that allows you to rebind an identifier while unwrapping an `Optional`. A `let` statement by itself can't rebind an identifier declared in the same scope. Them's the rules.

Furthermore, you cannot use an `Optional` as if it were a `BooleanType`, which you're trying to do (since the conditional of `?:` has to be a `BooleanType`).

Also note that `print` returns `()` (the empty tuple, also known as the singleton instance of the `Void` type). So there's no reason to rebind `foo` to the return value of `print`.

This works, though it's not good style:

```
foo != nil ? print("set") : print("nil")
```

This is good style:

```
if foo != nil {
    print("set")
} else {
    print("nil")
}
```

Or this:

```
print(foo != nil ? "set" : "nil")
```

The following is worse in this case, but is a reasonable pattern when you need to transform the wrapped value if set, and provide a default if nil:

```
print(foo.map { _ in "set" } ?? "nil" )
```

If you just want to unwrap `foo` for use later in the function, without increasing the brace nesting level, you can use `guard`:

```
guard let foo = foo else {
    print("nil")
    return // you must return or throw or abort here in a guard statement
}

// Here foo has been rebound and is no longer optional.
print("set to \(foo)")
```